# How do i write a dictionary containing dictionaries to an excel file

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, numpy, xlsx

Am looking for a way to write the following dictionary to an excel file without having to unpack it say using pandas.

```
myDict = {'Custom Name 1/Hedge':
              {'Portfolio': 'Custom Name 1/Hedge',
               'Benchmark Date': '31-Jul-2019',
               'Start of Period Date': '31-Jul-2019',
               'Valuation Date': '30-Aug-2019',
               'End of Period Date': '30-Aug-2019',
               'Hedge Ratio': 100,
               'Porfolio Ccy': ['AUD', 'CAD', 'CHF', 'DKK', 'EUR', 'GBP', 'JPY', 'MXN', 'MYR', 'NOK', 'PLN', 'SEK', 'SGD', 'USD', 'ZAR'],
               'Benchmark': [0.016736, 0.01642, 0.001486, 0.004805, 0.310821, 0.058103, 0.216064, 0.007106, 0.00333, 0.002245, 0.005085, 0.003544, 0.003053, 0.346847, 0.004355],
               'Pair': ['USD/AUD', 'USD/CAD', 'USD/CHF', 'USD/DKK', 'USD/EUR', 'USD/GBP', 'USD/JPY', 'USD/MXN', 'USD/MYR', 'USD/NOK', 'USD/PLN', 'USD/SEK', 'USD/SGD', '', 'USD/ZAR'],
               'Proxy': ['', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', ''],
               'SOP Spot': [1.450852, 1.31315, 0.99, 6.70665, 0.89815, 0.816693, 108.575, 18.98225, 4.1265, 8.78235, 3.84925, 9.59315, 1.36855, '', 14.17375],
               'Cross Rate': [1.449168, 1.31233, 0.987296, 6.687912, 0.895823, 0.815408, 108.318414, 19.087695, 4.128895, 8.773942, 3.846129, 9.569747, 1.367916, '', 14.230457],
               'Value Date Cross Rate': [1.48423, 1.3288, 0.98945, 6.7706, 0.908059, 0.821119, 106.145, 20.06715, 4.2055, 9.10625, 3.97195, 9.8068, 1.3872, '', 15.18375],
               'Value Date Spot': [1.48423, 1.3288, 0.98945, 6.7706, 0.908059, 0.821119, 106.145, 20.06715, 4.2055, 9.10625, 3.97195, 9.8068, 1.3872, '', 15.18375],
               'Spot Return': [2.24882, 1.17775, -0.05559, 0.94452, 1.09125, 0.53902, -2.28932, 5.40635, 1.87849, 3.5569, 3.08916, 2.17859, 1.34443, '', 6.65185],
               'Carry Return': [0.11347, 0.06171, 0.27332, 0.27676, 0.25621, 0.15653, 0.24173, -0.52546, -0.05695, 0.09233, 0.07857, 0.23864, 0.04569, '', -0.37347],
               'Total Return': [2.36229, 1.23946, 0.21773, 1.22128, 1.34746, 0.69554, -2.04759, 4.88089, 1.82155, 3.64923, 3.16773, 2.41723, 1.39012, '', 6.27838],
               'Bmk Spot': [0.03764, 0.01934, -8e-05, 0.00454, 0.33918, 0.03132, -0.49464, 0.03842, 0.00626, 0.00799, 0.01571, 0.00772, 0.0041, '', 0.02897],
               'Bmk Carry': [0.0019, 0.00101, 0.00041, 0.00133, 0.07963, 0.00909, 0.05223, -0.00373, -0.00019, 0.00021, 0.0004, 0.00085, 0.00014, '', -0.00163],
               'Bmk Return': [0.03954, 0.02035, 0.00032, 0.00587, 0.41882, 0.04041, -0.44241, 0.03468, 0.00607, 0.00819, 0.01611, 0.00857, 0.00424, '', 0.02734],
               'Proxy Return': [2.36229, 1.23946, 0.21773, 1.22128, 1.34746, 0.69554, -2.04759, 4.88089, 1.82155, 3.64923, 3.16773, 2.41723, 1.39012, '', 6.27838],
               'Proxy Bmk': [0.03954, 0.02035, 0.00032, 0.00587, 0.41882, 0.04041, -0.44241, 0.03468, 0.00607, 0.00819, 0.01611, 0.00857, 0.00424, '', 0.02734],
               'Bmk Spot Total': 0.04647,
               'Bmk Carry Total': 0.14165,
               'Bmk Return Total': 0.1881,
               'Proxy Bmk Total': 0.1881},
```

this is what i expect to have

[image]

I have the following so far but all it does is write the keys

```
df = pd.DataFrame(data=myDict, index=[0])

df = (df.T)

# print (df)

df.to_excel('dict1.xlsx')
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You seem to have rows with blank cells i suggest iterating through the dictionary and inserting the blank cells then writing to CSV using DictWriter.